# Rails - FIND from database using actual object params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

Once Im viewing a video in my app, like /videos/7, id like to show other videos with the same category as the one being viewed.

So in my controller im using:

```
def show
    @category_videos = Video.where("category = Video.category")
end
```

And using in my view

```
<% @category_videos.each do |n| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But its not working, any suggestions please? Sorry im new to rails.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should find the video first and then all the videos belonging to that category

```
def show
  @video = Video.find params[:id]
  @category_videos = Video.where(["category_id = ? && id NOT IN (?)", @video.category_id, @video.id])
end
```

Comment: What if I want to exclude the video being watched from the list? How should I query that?

Comment: what should i replace the "?" with?

Comment: No need to replace `?` it is part of the query. Rails will replace `?` with the following items in the array.

Comment: It gives me a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Videos#show error. Any suggestions?

Comment: your videos table has column `category` or `category_id` ? Updated my answer assuming the column name is `category_id`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have

```
Video belongs_to category
Category has_many videos

@video = Video.find(params[:id])
@category_videos = @video.category.videos
```

Comment: Thanks you this works. What if I want to exclude the video being watched from the list? How should I query that?